# Make alias folder for git?

Tags: xcode, git

I have a 1 TB Mac server with two partitions: 100 GB for the system and software, 900 GB for any other files. My git folder is stored on the 900 GB partition. The partition is named `Other`.

Right now, to access my git repositories, I have to go here:

```
ssh://git@example.com:22/Volumes/Other/git/repo.git
```

Is it possible to create an alias of the `git` folder (the alias would be named `git`, too) and place it on the root of the first partition (`/`), so that I can just type in the following?

```
ssh://git@example.com:22/git/repo.git
```

I created the alias and I was unable to access the repository from the above address. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try linking the folder, as it will link the contents as well:

```
# sudo ln -s /Volumes/Other/git /git
```